# How to convert column to row in sql without using pivot

Tags: sql-server, join, pivot-table

I have been assigned to get the data in required format from two tables.

TableStaff :

```
StaffID | Staff Name
--------+-----------
 1      | John 
 2      | Jack
```

and TableLead

```
LeadID | LeadValue | LeadStaus | StaffID
-------+-----------+-----------+--------
  1    | 5000      | New       | 1
  2    | 8000      | Qualified | 1
  3    | 3000      | New       | 2
```

As you will notice `StaffID` is a foreign key referencing `TableStaff`.

I have to represent the data in following format

```
StaffID | StaffName | NewLeadCount | QualifiedLeadCount 
--------+-----------+--------------+-------------------
1       | John      |  1           |   1
2       | Jack      |  1           |   0
```

What I have tried till now is :

```
SELECT 
    COUNT([LeadID ]) AS LdCount, 'New' AS StageName  
FROM 
    [dbo].[TableLead] 
WHERE
    [LeadStaus] = 'New' 
UNION 
SELECT 
    COUNT([LeadID ]) AS LdCount, 'Qualified' AS StageName 
FROM 
    [dbo].[TableLead] 
WHERE
    [LeadStaus] = 'Qualified '
```

Any NULL spots should be replaced by 0. Can anyone show me the right direction to approach the problem ?

Comment: If you don't want to use (the restrictive) `PIVOT` operator, then use conditional aggregation instead.

Comment: Can you hint me on how to use it in regard to the above problem ?

Comment: Have a search of "Conditional Aggregation" or "Cross tab"; you'll find plenty of resources (including on this site). *Don't forget to include "SQL Server" in your search term as well.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend conditional aggregation:

```
select s.staffid, s.staffname, 
    sum(case when l.leadstatus = 'New'       then 1 else 0 end) as newLeadCount,
    sum(case when l.leadstatus = 'Qualified' then 1 else 0 end) as qualifiedLeadCount
from TableStaff s
inner join TableLead l on l.staffid = s.staffid
group by s.staffid, s.staffname
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. The solution was pretty simple and straightforward. Will there be any performance issues by using conditional aggregation when data size is huge.